# Is it possible to create a Google Cloud VMware Engine cluster without NSX?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My understanding is that the GCVE solution is highly engineered (vSphere+vSAN+NSX+optiona HCX) and that NSX is not a choice: guest virtual machines *must* be attached to NSX network segments. I kindly ask for a confirmation on that.

In other words, within a Google VMware cluster it is not possible to use legacy (distributed or not) port groups.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, GCVE does not give you the option of whether you wish to deploy vSAN and NSX.  Strictly speaking, HCX is deployed by default as well, but you do not have to use it.

With that said, you *CAN create "legacy" port groups using standard vlans and at least route them between projects.  Not sure about routing them out to the internet as I have not tried.